# multiple spinner but one in xml

Tags: android, view, spinner

Hi please look at my xml file, very straight and simple, one textView and one Spinner

```
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewContactNamesTexting"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="name" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/font" android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>

            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:id="@+id/SpinnerNumTexting"></Spinner>
```

in run time I would like to generate as many as I want depending on an arrayList.
I attach the picture which explains my thought better.
any suggestion?
I know how to fill the spinner appropriately, just stuck on generating more than one :(

thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), with a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).  A quick Google search will turn up a number of tutorials on using a `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: you mean that in xml i put one listView and then inflate the layout in code and then pushing them in listView?

Comment: A ListView and adapter allows you to provide a list of items, and it will create one row for each item.  See the hello ListView tutorial for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooo yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee, thanks my friend, first comment was completely understanding and complete. thanks.